# Cannot read property 'quantity' of undefined

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

### Goal

I am trying to insert an ion-select value to an array.

### Problem

Cannot read property '0' of undefined. I suppose it comes from the file order-menu.html, under the code `orderArray[i].quantity`

### My Code

I have a model file **order-array.ts**

```
export interface OrderArray {
  $key?: string,
  menuName: string,
  menuPrice: string,
  quantity: string
}
```

and **order.ts**

```
export interface Order {
  custName: string,
  custPhone: string,
  restoName: string,
  restoPhone: string,
  restoAddress: string,
  message: string,
  orderArray: string
}
```

Here is my **order-menu.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList, AngularFireAction, DatabaseSnapshot } from '@angular/fire/database';

import { ProfileCust } from './../../models/profile-cust';
import { ProfileResto } from './../../models/profile-resto';
import { Menu } from './../../models/menu';
import { Order } from './../../models/order';
import { OrderArray } from './../../models/order-array';

import { OrderCustPage } from '../order-cust/order-cust';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-order-menu',
  templateUrl: 'order-menu.html',
})
export class OrderMenuPage {

  today: number = Date.now(); //get current time

  menuRef: AngularFireList<Menu>;
  menuData: Observable<AngularFireAction<DatabaseSnapshot<Menu>>[]>;

  //retrieve customer & resto profile
  profileCust: Observable<ProfileCust>;
  profileResto: Observable<ProfileResto>;

  restoData: {key: string}; //this parameter is passed from HomePage

  menu = {} as Menu;
  order = {} as Order;

  public orderArray : OrderArray[] = [];

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private afDatabase: AngularFireDatabase,
    private toast: ToastController,
    public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
      this.restoData = navParams.get('restoDataPass');
  }

ngOnInit(){
    let dataArray = {
      menuName: 'Name',
      menuPrice: '15000',
      quantity: 1
    }
    this.orderArray.push(dataArray);
    console.log(dataArray);
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(data => {
      if(data && data.email && data.uid){
        this.menuRef = this.afDatabase.list<Menu>(`menu/${this.restoData.key}`);
        this.menuData = this.menuRef.snapshotChanges();

        console.log(this.orderArray);
        // assign the values from profile customer model to order-customer model
        this.profileCust = <Observable<ProfileCust>>this.afDatabase.object(`profile-cust/${data.uid}`).valueChanges();
        this.profileCust.subscribe(res => {
            this.order.custName = res.custName;
            this.order.custPhone = res.custPhone
          //   var d = new Date();
          //  this.order.timestamp = d.getTime()
          }
        );

        // assign the values from profile resto model to order-resto model
        this.profileResto = <Observable<ProfileResto>>this.afDatabase.object(`profile-resto/${this.restoData.key}`).valueChanges();
        this.profileResto.subscribe(res => {
            this.order.restoName = res.restoName;
            this.order.restoPhone = res.restoPhone;
            this.order.restoAddress = res.restoAddress
          }
        );

      }
      else {
      }
    });
  }

  orderMenu(){
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(data => {
      if(data && data.email && data.uid){
        // write this order to DB node order-resto
        this.order.orderArray = this.orderArray.toString();
        console.log(this.orderArray);
        this.afDatabase.list(`order-resto/${this.restoData.key}`).push(this.order);

        // write this order to DB node order-cust
        this.afDatabase.list(`order-cust/${data.uid}`).push(this.order);

        this.navCtrl.setRoot(OrderCustPage);
        console.log(this.orderArray);

        this.toast.create({
          message: `Menu sudah dipesan`,
          duration: 3000
        }).present();
      }
      else {
        this.toast.create({
          message: `Mohon mendaftar terlebih dahulu di Menu - Masuk`,
          duration: 3000
        }).present();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

And **order-menu.html**

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar color="primary">
    <ion-title>OrderMenu</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let data of menuData | async ; let i = index ">
      <div item-content>
        <h2>Menu Name: {{data.payload.val().menuName}}</h2>
        <p>Price: {{data.payload.val().menuPrice}}</p>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>
            Quantity:
          </ion-label>
          <ion-select [(ngModel)]="orderArray[i].quantity">
            <ion-option value="1">1</ion-option>
            <ion-option value="2">2</ion-option>
          </ion-select>
        </ion-item>
      </div>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

  <ion-item item-content>
    <ion-label floating>Catatan</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="order.message"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <button ion-button (click)="orderMenu()">Order</button>

</ion-content>
```

-- *updated 25 October 2018*

I have added `ngOnInit(){...}` (see the code above). And when I print in console.log, I can see that the value inside the array is already assigned. However I still get the same error **Cannot read property 'quantity' of undefined**

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure `orderArray` has elements?

Comment: I have updated my question. Thanks Frank

Answer (score 1):

The error is straight forward, you are trying to set a ngModel value which is undefined. As your array is empty and it does not have any elements you are trying to set the index there. Either have your array defined or use a different variable to set the selected value.

After the line

```
if(data && data.email && data.uid){
    this.menuRef = this.afDatabase.list<Menu>(`menu/${this.restoData.key}`);
    this.menuData = this.menuRef.snapshotChanges();
```

add this to assign initial value to `orderArray[i].quantity`:

```
this.menuData.subscribe(result => {
          for (let i=0; i<result.length; i++){
            let dataArray = {
              menuName: result[i].payload.val().menuName,
              menuPrice: result[i].payload.val().menuPrice,
              quantity: 0
            }
            this.orderArray.push(dataArray);
            console.log(dataArray); //to logthe dataArray
          }
          console.log(result); //to log the result
          console.log(this.orderArray); //to log the orderArray
        });
```

Comment: How to define the array? Maybe I can set the default values. But how to do it? Thanks

Comment: push the elements to the array by using orderArray.push(yourObj)

Comment: I'm sorry. Where to put that line? Is that to set the default value?

Comment: anywhere in the controller before you access in the component

Comment: thanks for your reply. Sorry I'm really new to programming. I have updated my code above. Now where to put the `orderArray.push(yourObj)` and what is the `yourObj`?

Comment: since you are using menudata, can you try this ? <ion-select [(ngModel)]="data[i].quantity">

Comment: That results to "Cannot read property 'quantity' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

To initialize your orderArray before use it, in ngOnInit method push your elements to the array, like this :

```
ngOnInit() {
  orderArray.push(obj);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, where to put that line? I have updated my code above.

Comment: Hi @Charlie, I have updated my code above using ngOnInit. I have been able to assign initial value, however the same error persists